# Querydsl Like Surprise

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, jpql, querydsl

I have just dabbled into using Querydsl, and am thoroughly enjoying the improvement it brings to interacting with JPA.

One remaining question I have is why do you have to wrap a `like` parameter with `%`?

Have I improperly configured something? Considering there is a method for `starts/endsWith`, I assumed `like(str)` would automatically wrap my `str`.

But to my surprise I needed to do this: `"%" + str + "%"` to get what I had expected.

Why is that? Is there a better way?

Comment: A random though would be how would it know whether to prefix and suffix with "%" or only suffix: or,  for that matter only prefix. '%a%' 'a%' and '%a' are different queries?

Comment: The QueryDSL `StringPath` class has `contains` and `containsIgnoreCase` method that automatically prepend and append the `%` symbol.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5703687/703644) contains does a lot of different stuff. Is that not a correct reading?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is. (At least in QueryDSL 4.1.3), there is a `contains(String s)` method and variants of it (containsIgnoreCase etc.). This is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`Like` is there to do custom wildcard matching (the algorithm expect you to add the `%` characters by yourself and wherever you feel they are needed).

Apart from `StartsWith` / `EndsWith` which have implicit `%` characters.. there is **Containing** keyword which prepends and appends the `%` character. And this is what you are looking for here.

```
findByAttributeContaining(String charset);
```

Documentation example: [spring jpa examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: I don't see `findByAttributeContaining` i do see the contains operation but based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5703687/703644) i though that was fundamentally different than starts & ends with

Comment: Check the example i added.. it clearly states: parameter bound wrapped in %. The Attribute in my example can be eny attribute that you want to match to the charset

Comment: This answer would seem to be talking about Spring Data derived queries and not QueryDsl, which was the subject of the original question.