# How to write 'like' along with array operation query in QueryDsl using predicate

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl

I have a varchar field in PostgreSQL, let's say the column is 'address' and list is ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']. I want to find any row in my table that has any of those words.

How do I write it using BoolenBuilder to create predicate? or by any means

```
final var builder = new BooleanBuilder();
builder.and(qAccount.accAddress.eqAny(accountAddress.getAddressLine()));


Predicate predicate = builder.getValue();
```

** here ArrayPath<String[], String> accAddress1 = qAccount.accAddress;

Answer (score 0):

The like operation is handled by using the `like()` or `contains()` functions (the diff is described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562483/querydsl-like-surprise)), so since you want to find any row that contains any of the words from your list, you would have to iterate and add **each** condition to your `BooleanBuilder`, something like this:

```java
final var builder = new BooleanBuilder();

for (String address : accountAddress.getAddressLine()) {
    builder.or(qAccount.accAddress.like("%" + address + "%"));
}

Predicate predicate = builder.getValue();
```