# How can i use `contains` in oracle for fast full text searching for text but i want it to work as `like` %texthere%

Tags: sql, oracle, contains

Is it possible to get functionality  same as `like`

I want this because i have 6 million record to search .

I have record in table

```
himanshux 
himanshhggge jshsd

select * from user_detail where fistname like %hh%
select * from user_detail where CONTAINS(fistname,'hh',1) > 0
```

and also what is difference between ?

`CONTAINS(fistname,'hh',1) > 0` and `CONTAINS(fistname,'%hh%',1) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to reference this question here:

[search criteria difference between Like vs Contains() in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700795/search-criteria-difference-between-like-vs-contains-in-oracle)

Your syntax for using CONTAINS() works properly in the first example

Your second question, what is the difference between:

```
CONTAINS(fistname,'hh',1) > 0 and CONTAINS(fistname,'%hh%',1) > 0
```

The difference is the first `CONTAINS(fistname,'hh',1) > 0` is searching for an independent "hh" word

In the second `CONTAINS(fistname,'%hh%',1) > 0`, it is searching for any instance of the string "hh" regardless of what is before or after it.

Comment: Instead of independent string, I'd say "separate word". 'hhello' would not match 'hh', but it would match '%hh%'.