# Optimizing Oracle Queries - functions in the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have been told time and time again that the best way to optimize a query is to remove functions in the where clause. Functions cause a full table scan.  So my question is, given these three queries, why does the one with the functions in the where clause  (Exhibit C) perform the best - more than twice as fast?

Exhibit A - uppercase the text in the with so there is no function in the where clause but still putting the where clause in the select

```
With Code As (
Select owner,name,Upper(text) As text,line From all_source
)
select * from Code
Where text Like '%UPPER(%'
And owner='COMMISSIONS'
```

Exhibit B - uppercase the text in the with and filtering as much as we can

```
With Code As (
Select owner,name,Upper(text) As text,line From all_source
Where owner='COMMISSIONS'
)
select * from Code
Where text Like '%UPPER(%'
```

Exhibit C - no with clause and a function in the where clause

```
select * from all_source
Where upper(text) Like '%UPPER(%'
And owner='COMMISSIONS'
```

Comment: I am guessing that you have an index on `owner` and the three have pretty similar performance.

Comment: In order to answer your question appropriately we need to know what indexes the table `all_source` has. Without that information we can barely guess.

Comment: For example, your query #3 will be probably faster if you create the following index: `create index ix1 on all_source (owner, upper(text));`. Do it and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR -- Your third query probably ran fastest because of caching.  It is neither better nor worse, performance-wise, than the other two.  But it is simplest and it is the one you should use.**

> > why does the one with the functions in the where clause (Exhibit C) perform the best?

All three of your queries are basically the same, after Oracle's optimizer gets through with them.  If the third one ran faster, it is likely because there are indexes in the tables underlying the `ALL_SOURCE` view that are being used because you specified `owner = 'COMMISSIONS'`.  The index blocks and table blocks accessed using the index are eligible for storage in the block buffer cache.  Your third query is benefiting from the first two having already read and cached some of the data it needs.  (Proof?  Run the 1st query again).

More importantly though: "remove functions from the WHERE clause" is not an exact way of describing the conventional advice.

The conventional advice exists to help new Oracle developers be aware of the limitations of indexes.

Take out your favorite technical reference and go to the index at the back.  Use it to find the topics and page numbers for each topic starting with "so".  The index is very helpful, right?  Now use the index to find the topics and page numbers ending in "r" (analogous Oracle function is "substr(topic,-1) = 'r'").  The index is not useful at all anymore.  Oracle indexes suffer from the same limitations.

Now, the authors of your technical reference could have created a second index at the back that organized all the topics according to their last letter.  If they had done so, that index would have been very useful for the second exercise I gave you, above.  Similarly, Oracle can create "function-based" indexes to answer queries based on that function (e.g., substr(topic,-1)).

But, in the absence of a pre-existing function-based index, queries filtering on a function of a column do not benefit from an index on that column.  It's a generalization (there are exceptions, like "covering" indexes), but it's a good generalization.

None of that is specifically about the function being in the `WHERE` clause though.  All three of your queries would prevent Oracle from using an index on `TEXT`.  Avoiding a "function in the `WHERE` clause" by using a view or `WITH` clause to perform the function doesn't get you around the limitations of Oracle indexes.

(Aside: The fact that you are using the `LIKE` operator on the `TEXT` column is another big reason why an index would not help -- see Oracle Text feature for better options like the `CONTAINS` operator).

Comment: Very Helpful.  Here is a reference to Like vs Contains.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700795/search-criteria-difference-between-like-vs-contains-in-oracle